# Count unread message by tag

Tags: privatemsg

I am trying to display the number of unread message for each individual tag. I found it's possible to use `privatemsg_unread_count()` or create a query with `_privatemsg_assemble_query('list', $user, 'inbox')`.

How do I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_privatemsg_assemble_query()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/privatemsg/-/blob/7.x-1.x/privatemsg.module?ref_type=heads#L2039) or [`privatemsg_unread_count()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/privatemsg/-/blob/7.x-1.x/privatemsg.module?ref_type=heads#L848). The latter returns the number of unread messages for an account.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $count = _privatemsg_assemble_query('list', $user,'My_tags_name');
$unread = privatemsg_unread_count($count);
 if($unread > 0)
  { 
   echo '<div class="height:50px;">'.$unread. 'new messages</div>';
  } else { 
 }
```

or

```
$query = _privatemsg_assemble_query('list', $user, 'inbox');
$total_count = db_result(db_query($query['count'])); 
echo $total_count;
```